# Laravel Forge server stuck on provisioning

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-forge

**My Setup:**

- AWS server running Ubuntu 14.04
- Laravel Forge account linked to AWS account
- Bitbucket repo containing the Laravel project

**The problem:**

I have provisioned and used two servers before using Laravel Forge with this set up and it worked fine. I had to recreate the servers, and when I did the provisioning script gets stuck - what I mean by this is that it finished running the script as normal, but instead of restarting the server at the end it just stops - and on the Laravel Forge page it says *"Making Final Server Tweaks."* constantly in the recent events, and the server never stops provisioning. I left it doing this overnight and it was still the same the next morning.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

In case anyone else has the same issue -

In this particular case I had to refresh my Bitbucket tokens on my Laravel Forge page, which fixed the issue.

Comment: How is this related to instaling a server?